# ¿Cual es el orden de ejecución correcto de las sentencias sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una duda existencial sobre el orden de ejecución de las sentencias **SQL**, específicamente en la unión de tablas relacionadas. Primero se ejecuta el `FROM` despues la clausula `ON` y despues el `INNER JOIN` de cada tabla ?. Si alguien pudiera aclararme ya que  frecuentemente tengo resultados erroneos en mis consultas y quiero entender esta parte de el orden de ejecución.
De antemano gracias a todos.

```
    SELECT h.SalesOrderID,
           h.OrderDate,
           h.SalesOrderNumber,
           h.TotalDue,
           d.ProductID,
           d.LineTotal,
           p.Name
      FROM AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS h
INNER JOIN AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS d
        ON h.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN AdventureWorks.Production.Product AS p
        ON d.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

Comment: se ejecuta todo completo no en partes, si no imaginate siempre leeria completas todas las tablas, inner join te va a traer solo los datos que existan en las 2 tablas, en tu caso tienes dos inner join por lo que te va a traer solo los datos que existan en las 3 tablas con las condiciones que pusiste en el on

Comment: me refería mas a la respuesta de @M.Narcher, suena un poco tonta mi pregunta pero también pensé que se ejecutaba todo completo hasta que tuve problemas en los resultados de mis consultas y me mencionaron que era por el orden logico de procesamiento de la consulta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La mejor manera de comprender tanto el orden como el coste de una consulta es a traves de la herramienta de Plan de Ejecución que te proporciona el Sql Management Studio. [Aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-2017) tienes la documentación oficial, pero te pongo un ejemplo simple de una consulta similar a la tuya para que lo veas:

```
SELECT  j.id AS idJornada, j.nombre, j.descripcion, j.color,
        s.id AS idSesion, s.horaInicio, s.horaFinal
FROM Jornadas j 
LEFT JOIN JornadaSesiones js ON j.id = js.idJornada
LEFT JOIN Sesiones s ON s.id = js.idSesion
WHERE s.id = 1
```

Activando el Plan de Ejecución y despues de ejecutar la consulta veo lo siguiente (se lee de derecha a izquierda):

[image: PLan de Ejecución]

Como puedes ver primero hace el join de "Jornadas" y "JornadaSesiones", al resultado le aplica el join junto a "Sesiones" previo filtrado por la busqueda del WHERE (si te fijas pone Búsqueda en índice en lugar de Examen en índice) y sobre el resultado aplica el SELECT.

Esta herramienta da mucho mas de sí, pero puede servir para hacerte una idea de lo que pides.

Comment: Mas claro ni el agua M,Nacher, leí que SQL Server va generando tablas temporales que son entrada de otra operación. Me quedo super claro amigo. Gracias por la referencia y tu tiempo.